# Split data into 3 column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble parsing a data file into a data frame. When I read the data using pandas I get a one column data frame with all the information.

```
Server    
7.14.182.917 - - [20/Dec/2018:08:30:21 -0500] "GET /tools/performance/log/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.23.5.min.js HTTP/1.1" 235 89583
7.18.134.196 - - [20/Dec/2018:07:40:13 -0500] "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" 502 -
...
```

I want to parse the data in three columns. I tried using `df[['Server', 'Date', 'Address']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split() for x in df['Server'].tolist() ])` but I'm getting an error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`
Is there a way to parse the data to have 3 columns as follows

```
Server        Date                          Address                               
7.14.182.917  20/Dec/2018:08:30:21 -0500.   "GET /tools/performance/log/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.23.5.min.js HTTP/1.1" 235 89583
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple approaches can be taken here depending on the input file type and format. If the file is a valid string path, try these approaches [(more here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
# approach 1
df = pd.read_fwf('inputfile.txt')

# approach 2
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.txt", sep = "\t") # check the delimiter

# then select the columns you want
df_subset = df[['Server', 'Date', 'Address']]
```

---

Full solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read in text file
df = pd.read_csv("test_input.txt", sep=" ", error_bad_lines=False)

# convert df to string
df = df.astype(str)

# get num rows
num_rows = df.shape[0]

# get IP from index, then reset index
df['IP'] = df.index

# reset index to proper index
new_index = pd.Series(list(range(num_rows)))
df = df.set_index([new_index])

# rename columns and drop old cols
df = df.rename(columns={'Server': 'Date', 'IP': "Server"})

# create Date col, drop old col
df['Date'] = df.Date.str.cat(df['Unnamed: 1'])
df = df.drop(["Unnamed: 1"], axis=1)

# Create address col, drop old col
df['Address'] = df['Unnamed: 2'] + df['Unnamed: 3'] + df['Unnamed: 4']
df = df.drop(["Unnamed: 2","Unnamed: 3","Unnamed: 4"], axis=1)

# Strip brackets, other chars
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip("[]")
df['Server'] = df["Server"].astype(str)
df['Server'] = df['Server'].str.strip("()-'', '-',")
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work because the ['Server', 'Date', 'Address'] are not names that exist in the data. I want to split the one column into 3 and make headers for each

Comment: First you need to read in the data. Both `read_fwf` or `read_csv` will read the data into a dataframe and automatically create columns. Then you can rename them using `df.rename(columns={"A": "a", "B": "c"})`. It does work.

Comment: The data doesn't have a header when you read it you have to add a headder and when it reads it it puts all the info in one column dataframe. It doesn't split it. So if I do what you suggest it would give me an error since it reads it as one column

Comment: That is what I did on my first try but as I say I only get one column not 3. There's not indices for other columns

Comment: What kind of file is it and what is the delimiter between columns?

Comment: It's and .xz file. What I show in my original post is basically the first 2 lines of the file with the exception of the header. I think it doesn't read any space

Comment: Just posted the solution. Feel free to modify to suit your exact needs

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references