# Search text from web scrape and transform next 4 lines into a python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Ive been able to scrape some text off a website but having trouble trying to transform the text into some sort of dataframe (preferrably to then use with pandas)

output from `print(text)` webscrape gives me all the text:

```
Example text paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Section 1 - "Summary"
1 - sdgge
2 - hjsdhdc
3 - sahdfda
4 - sahfdfds
Example text paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Section 2 - "Introduction"
1 - abcdef
2 - jhfdgsa
3 - sadgffe
4 - sdjddasd
```

My next step is trying to transform the data into a table that has:

```
Section 1 | Summary      | 1 - sdgge | 2 - hjsdhdc | 3 - sahdfda| 4 - sahfdfds|
Section 2 | Introduction | 1 - abcdef| 2 - jhfdgsa | 3 - sadgffe| 4 - sdjddasd|
```

with sections going up to 10-15 in text text

The Sections are randomly spread throughout other paragraphs so is it possible to search for "Section 1" and then return the 4 lines underneath and so on?

thanks very much!

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997482/split-data-into-3-column-dataframe/60997715#60997715) might be partially helpful to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***edited***

I would approach this by iterating through each line with regex logic:

```
my_lines = my_text.split("\n")

# instantiate an empty list of records
records = []

my_patterns = {
    "section":re.compile("section\s*[0-9]+", re.I),
    "1":re.compile('1 - ([a-z]+)'),
    "2":re.compile('2 - ([a-z]+)'),
    "3":re.compile('3 - ([a-z]+)'),
    "4":re.compile('4 - ([a-z]+)')
    }
rec = {}

# Loop through each line, perform logic
for x in my_lines:

  for key, pattern in my_patterns.items():
    if pattern.search(x):

      # get the value
      my_value = pattern.findall(x)[0]

      if key == "section":
        # save the records
        if len(rec)>0:
            records.append(rec)

        # start a new record
        rec = {}


      # always add to the record
      rec[key] = my_value

# # when done looping, add the last record
records.append(rec)

# # convert to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(records)


    section     1       2       3       4
0   Section 1   sdgge   hjsdhdc sahdfda sahfdfds
1   Section 2   abcdef  jhfdgsa sadgffe sdjddasd
```

Comment: Thanks very much @yaakov. I should have metioned that the numbers underneath each section are random and could be a string of text and not just one number. I will update the questions to reflect.

Comment: is my_lines referring to the text?

Comment: The output i am getting it just every character in the body of text is in its own column. Thats by directing `my_lines` to the `text`

Comment: share a sample of your text @SOK

Comment: I have updated the sample above in the original question when i execute `print(text)`

Comment: Edited my response for your specifics @SOK

Comment: Thanks @yaakov. Ive got it working however some of the numbers underneath the sections are not always 1,2,3,4 so thats what is complicating things (and not always numbers either). Would there be a way to just take the whole text of the line directly underneath "Section 1" and then the whole text that is the 2nd line underneath "Section 1" etc?

Comment: These additional follow ups is not what SO is intended for @SOK – if you have an additional Q, I'd suggest you post as a new Q

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, I'd appreciate if you could accept it as the answer @SOK